# Redmine Issue Creation Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am currently writing a plugin the creates a new issue via a http post request. I am currently Having issues with creating and saving a new issue. Every time I cal issue.save, it returns false. I was hoping that someone would point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance

Here is the code I currently have:

```
issue = Issue.new
issue.tracker = Tracker.find_by_name("Bug")
issue.subject = params[:subject]
issue.description = params[:description]
issue.project = Project.find_by_name(params[:project])
issue.start_date = Time.now.localtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
issue.priority = IssuePriority.find_by_name("Normal")
issue.author = User.find_by_mail("XXX@gmail.com")
issue.status = IssueStatus.find_by_name("New")
issue.save
```

Comment: Are you sure the issue object you are going to save is valid? You can check it by calling `issue.valid?` method or save it without validattion calling save(false). You can just check validation messages: issue.errors.full_messages afeter save.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Redmine already has a REST API which allows issue creation. Here's the issues API docs: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues

Comment: I need the ability to post a exception report to redmine. Once redmine receives the report, it needs to either create a new issue, OR update an existing issue (increasing count, and other information). The client side application does not know if a report being file is new or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your quick responses, They have helped me significantly.

After calling `issue.errors.full_messages` , I discovered that I could not save the issue because required custom fields were not set.

I added the following code before calling issue.save

```
  issue.custom_values = [
    create_custom_value(CustomField.find_by_name("StackTrace").id, params[:stackTrace]),
    ... more custom values ...
  ]
```

also here is my create_custom_value method

```
# returns a new custom value
def create_custom_value(field_id, value)
  custom_value = CustomValue.new
  custom_value.custom_field_id = field_id
  custom_value.value = value
  custom_value.customized_type = "Issue"
  return custom_value
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Some error occurs! Examine issue.errors to check which:

```
Rails.logger.info issue.errors.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Issues (and do many other things) in Redmine using [REST API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues).